# Dovecot:/Thunderbird sslv3 alert certificate expired: SSL alert number 45

Tags: email, thunderbird, dovecot

Thunderbird is silently failing to fetch messages for one of my mail servers. Looking in the server's dovecot logs I got the error message in the title, specifically:

```
imap-login: Info: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=[IP redacted], lip=[IP redacted], TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() failed: error:14094415:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate expired: SSL alert number 45, session=<Y/pyl7D8zuYXXew+>
```

I checked my certificates, which are LetsEncrypt certs I also use for the web server and, in a web browser, they showed as up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dovecot does not reload the certificates if it is not restarted. So when I restarted dovecot, it loaded the new versions of the certificates, and voila all was well. Notably, I had a dovecot reload in crontab, but I guess that extends only to configs and not to certs. I changed it to a restart for a hopefully more permanent fix.